# Reindexing bamboo through a task

Tags: bamboo

I am trying to automate bamboo reindexing (Bamboo UI -> Overview -> Indexing -> Perform a full reindex)

Can this be done through a task or plugin or any other automated way?

Answer (score 0):

Use REST APIs for that.
This CURL command might help you.

curl -u adminuserid:adminpassword -X POST  https://localhost:8085/rest/api/latest/reindex

Please note admin should have sysadmin permisisons to perform reindexing.